# How to cover method inside arrayList in mockito junits

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to cover below main class **if (!Utility.isEmpty(errors))** block code coverage and i tried below code for adding errors in array List inside client class but still array showing as empty can some one help me to solve this issue.

### Main class

```
public void processDiohShippingMethod(ShippingMethodRequest request) {
        List<ResolvableErrorEnum> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        checkoutRestClient.updateShippingMethod(request, errors);
        if (!Utility.isEmpty(errors)) {
            logger.info("ProcessDiohShippingMethod: Shipping method update failure  from {} -> {}. Reverting. ",
                    existingSm, request.getShippingMethodType());
            if (existingShippingMethod != null && Constants.RTG_ENJOY.equalsIgnoreCase(existingSm)) {
                request.setStartTime(existingShippingMethod.getDropOffShippingInfo().getStartTime());
                request.setEndTime(existingShippingMethod.getDropOffShippingInfo().getEndTime());
                request.setScheduleType(existingShippingMethod.getDropOffShippingInfo().getCustomerScheduleType());
            }
        }
    }
```

### Client

```
public void updateShippingMethod(ShippingMethodRequest request, List<ResolvableErrorEnum> errors) {
    String url = Utils.formatHttpUrl(url, Cart_Request);
    try {
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request);
        JsonNode jsonNode = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, JsonNode.class);
        if (!jsonNode.has(Constants.CONTENT)
                || !jsonNode.path(Constants.CONTENT).path(Constants.ERRORS).isMissingNode()) {
            errors.add(ErrorMessages.SM_ERR_01);
            return;
        }
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        errors.add(ErrorMessages.SM_ERR_01);
    } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
        errors.add(ErrorMessages.SM_ERR_01);
    }
}
```

### Test

```
@Test
    public void test_processMethod() throws Exception {
        Request req = new Request();
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(req);
        String jsonResponse = "{\"error\":{\"errorId\":\"1234\",\"message\":\"error message\"}},\"status\":\"success\"}}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonResponse);
        when(restTemplate.postForObject("url", entity, JsonNode.class)).thenReturn(actualObj);

        ShippingMethodResponse response = helper.processDiohShippingMethod(req);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the whole test code this is just an educated guess, but the most probable cause is that your `helper` object (the one from the test method) uses a different instance, but not the one you mocked (since I can't see any code in the test, that would set the client).

So a solution could look like this:

```
@Test
public void test_processMethod() throws Exception {
    Request req = new Request();
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(req);
    String jsonResponse = "{\"error\":{\"errorId\":\"1234\",\"message\":\"error message\"}},\"status\":\"success\"}}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(jsonResponse);
    when(restTemplate.postForObject("url", entity, JsonNode.class)).thenReturn(actualObj);

    //get this mocked object into the helper object somehow
    //otherwhise the mocked method will never be called
    helper.setClient(restTemplate);

    ShippingMethodResponse response = helper.processDiohShippingMethod(req);
}
```

You probably assumed the mocking call `when(restTemplate.postForObject(...))...` to mock the method for all objects of this class. But **it will just create a decorator- / wrapper-object arround the object**. So you've got to make shure that you call the mocked method on the mocked object, but not on any other object.

Comment: how can we get mocked object into helper class?

Comment: have you tried using a setter method like in the code snippet? If this doesn't work you could also try to refactor it into a parameter.